# Where in the Bible did God tell Adam and Eve that they have sinned?

Tags: adam-and-eve, verse-identification

I was wondering where in the Bible I can find that God told Adam and Eve that they have sinned after they have eaten the forbidden fruit from the tree.

Comment: Have you read any of the book of Genesis?

Comment: [Verse search questions are problematic](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4200/6071). For your question to be allowed here, please edit this to specify the *exact* wording searched for (and preferably give several alternatives they tried), as well as tell us what passages those searches suggested and why they are wrong. Without telling us these things, your question is just duplicating the work of a search engine.

Answer (score 5):

Sin is described in the Bible as transgression of the law of God (1 John 3:4) and rebellion against God (Deuteronomy 9:7; Joshua 1:18).  After creating Adam, God issued only one prohibition in His instructions:

> “The Lord God took the man and put him in the Garden of Eden to work it and keep it.  And the Lord God commanded the man, saying, “You may surely eat of every tree of the garden,  but of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat, for in the day that you eat of it you shall surely die” (Genesis 2:15-17).

It was only after Adam and Eve disobeyed God’s command, after they had eaten of the fruit of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil that “their eyes were opened” – and they tried to hide from God:

> “But the Lord God called to the man and said to him, “Where are you?” And he said, “I heard the sound of you in the garden, and I was afraid, because I was naked, and I hid myself.”  He said, “Who told you that you were naked? Have you eaten of the tree of which I commanded you not to eat?”  The man said, “The woman whom you gave to be with me, she gave me fruit of the tree, and I ate.”  Then the Lord God said to the woman, “What is this that you have done?” The woman said, “The serpent deceived me, and I ate” (Genesis 3:7-13).

God does not use the word “sin” when he pronounces judgment on Adam and Eve for their disobedience.  But God does say WHY they have sinned against Him.  God says to Adam:

> “Because you have listened to the voice of your wife and have eaten of the tree of which I commanded you, ‘You shall not eat of it,’ cursed is the ground because of you; in pain you shall eat of it all the days of your life; thorns and thistles it shall bring forth for you; and you shall eat the plants of the field. By the sweat of your face you shall eat bread, till you return to the ground, for out of it you were taken; for you are dust, and to dust you shall return” (Genesis 3:17-19).

Adam and Eve succumbed to the temptation “to be like God, knowing good and evil” (Genesis 3:4).  They disobeyed God – and they knew they had done wrong.  That is the original sin that “came into the world through one man” – Adam – and a direct consequence of that sin is death:

> “Therefore, just as sin came into the world through one man, and death through sin, and so death spread to all men because all sinned—  for sin indeed was in the world before the law was given, but sin is not counted where there is no law.  Yet death reigned from Adam to Moses, even over those whose sinning was not like the transgression of Adam, who was a type of the one who was to come” (Romans 5:12-14).

Through Adam sin entered the world, and so death was passed on to all men because “the wages of sin is death” (Romans 6:23).  That is what the Bible has to say about sin and how it originated.  Adam and Eve disobeyed God because they wanted “to be like God, knowing good and evil.”  That is sin.

Comment: Is the question about sinniing after eating, not before?

Comment: My answer simply quotes from the Bible about the events leading up to Adam and Eve's disobedience, God's judgmen,t and what the Bible has to say about sin. It's always advisable to put Scripture into context to get the full picture, don't you think?

Comment: I did not understand the question was about sin in general, after Adam and Eve ate from the forbidden tree in the Garden. If I am mistaken, perhaps the O.P. could edit the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

[Genesis 3:14-19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+3&version=NIV)

In the New Internation Version it reads

> 14. So the Lord God said to the serpent, “Because you have done this,
>       Cursed are you above all livestock and all wild animals! You will crawl on your belly and you will eat dust all the days of your life.
> 15. And I will put enmity between you and the woman, and between your offspring and hers; he will crush your head, and you will strike his heel.”
> 16. To the woman he said, “I will make your pains in childbearing very severe; with painful labor you will give birth to children. Your desire will be for your husband, and he will rule over you."
> 17. To Adam he said, “Because you listened to your wife and ate fruit from the tree about which I commanded you, ‘You must not eat from it,’ Cursed is the ground because of you; through painful toil you will eat food from it all the days of your life.
> 18. It will produce thorns and thistles for you, and you will eat the plants of the field.
> 19. By the sweat of your brow you will eat your food until you return to the ground, since from it you were taken;
>       for dust you are and to dust you will return.”

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a common misconception, look at Genisis3

Several things stand out. 
1. God never told Adam he could not touch the fruit or look at the fruit. Adam improperly instructed Eve on the will of God, or she added to the word because she did not fully understand. Again, due to either not asking enough wuedtions or Adam failing to teach her properly. But clearly, Eve did not respect what Adam had told her. She chose to ignore his role as firstborn of God and hearken to someone other tgan her husband when he was instructing her at least mostly right (which ultimately is what gave the serpent tgr powrr to deceive her... almost truth).

2. Also note, Adam was right there when she was being lied to. He obviously wanted the fruit but dared not taste it. Instead, he stood there and allowed his wife to eat it. He then accepted her leadership and seduction into sin. He did not say anything though. He took no authority and just stood there while she ate, tgen when she offered the fruit he accepted it and ate it. He never corrected her misunderstanding, nor did he stand up for God. He went slong with her sin as a weak man.
3. God NEVER punished either of them for eating the fruit. Nope. That is simply not truth. He punished the serpent for deception and seduction. He did NOT punish Adam and Eve for eating the fruit. He explained to them the consequences of their action, what the results would be. Their punishment came from themselves and from each other and from their generations to come.

He said Eve would suffer for HEAKENING to the serpent rather than to her husband and to God.. She "SHEMA" to the serpent. She was punished for being tbe first feminist.  Adam received the consequences of sin for HEARKENING to his wife. He SHEMA to his wife rather than God.

4. God first asked for an explanation from Adam for standing there letting his wife defy God. Adam immediately blamed both Eve and God himsrlf for giving him Eve. Wrong move buster. God listened, then patiently questioned Eve about her involvement. Eve never blamed her husband, instead, she told the truth, that the serpent tricked her. However, again, no personal accountability for her choice to hearken to the serpent.
5. So both received the same punishment.
6. God punished the serpent wothout questioning it.  He did so in front of his children. I think he did this order so that Adam and Eve could see the immediate consequences of their sin. No doubt the serpent was a beautiful animal that they both interacted with routinely. Now they saw it stripped of its power to move freely. Wow. That must have really impacted them.
7. Then God says to Eve that any future children she bears will enter a world of suffereing. She saw what just happened to tge serpent, so there could be no doubt in her mind that God was speaking truth. No more Adam between her and God. God was instructing her directly as to the results of her evil actions and choice. Wow, no good mother wants to know she will foever cause her own children to suffer. Not only that, her children will be born into her same rebellion. All will be brought forth in suffering and cause her suffering in their rebellion. Rather than giving birth to life, she and all her daughters will bring forth death. Her heart must have been absolutely broken.
8. Then God pronounces what appears to be an actual punishment on them jointlty.

Eve will desire her husband and he will rule over her. But again Godhad already established the heirarchy  So that her vulnerability and desire for his attention and love will lead to his oppression and controlling behavior. There will be struggles between them because she did not willingly submit to his authority as God esrablished; rather she submitted to the will of the serpent (evil) instead. Because part of hearkening is obedience, it means to turn toward, listen and obey.

Adam, will now be held accountable, not just for his own actions in properly instructing his wife and children,  but also for his righteous leadership and the actions of his wife and children, tgat is, the nations tgat come from his loins. Remember, God judges entire nations based on the actions of the leadership, because the people most iften follow the leader into depravity, just as the wife and children most often follow the husband and father into depravity. "Fruit doesn't fall far from the tree."

Ultimately, Adam (men) has been officially made watchman and will be held to a higher standard. If a man fails to lead his wife and children in love and submission to God, he will be judged for that. He can no longer blame his wife if his kids are reprobate. Why? Because a man CHOOSES A WIFE. So he better hearken to God when he does so. But if a man rules over his wife with weakness, control and abuse (oppression and the stripping away of free will), that is, in hearkening to her or to the serpent, with an authority he was never given by God, he commits the sin of presumption, which separates him from God.  Presumption being the acting with authority you were never given. The resulting punishment is that either she will hate his authority and rebel or his children will turn from God. How do we know that? Because his puishment is the same as Eve's.

9. Adam's first task was to tend the garden, name the animals, and eat the abundant fruit the garden provided under his care.  But now he has to pierce the soil, till it, vreak it open and cast the seeds for vread, wait on it to return food to him in season. All his labor will not bring forth good fruit but also, now bad fruit too. He and all men to come will know, as the thorns pierce their hands and feet, thst hearkening to any other but YHvH brings suffering. That is what he has doomed his children to.

In fact, the very labor God gave him in love will be a burden to him. He will work and rather than joy, earth will give him thorns. His fruit, just as the woman's fruit, will bring about suffering. God tells him, that the work he does to provide for any future children will not be responded to by the earth with pure abundance. Rather thorns will respond. Likewise, his efforts to teach his wife and children will be responded to with rebellion (thorns).Adam blamed the very person he was responsible for, and subsequent sons will do the same, blame their children and wives rather thsn seeing them as a gift from God, and so abandon them, abuse them, lord over tgem, strip them of free will because he fails to properly instruct them. He too brings forth death. Adam surely felt great grief at this.

10. Adam's  failure to listen only to God and to properly instruct and lead his wife lead to his burden, and his knowing that his children would receive thorns and rebellion rather than pure blessings as he received in love., must have been absolutely devastating to him.  What a huge burden to bear. He did not act to protect his wife. He did not intervede to drive off the serpent. He stood tgere are did nothing except go along with it. Nkw he will be forced to lead.
11. So no matter how much mam struggles, ultimatemy, that is his result, to toil earth and see his efforts bring forth suffering.  Woman, the same thing.  No matter how good a mother she is, one of the first words her chd will say to her as sokn as it can speak is, "No."  She will work to love her childre and support her husband and he will rule over her, causing her suffering and frustrations and oppression. He will seek to lead and be faced with rebellion and his own weakness as a man. Both will watch their children be born into suffering rather than abundance and they will lift up nstions of suffering.

But realuze, the punishment came from THEM. They chose that their master would be satan by choosing to hearken to the serpent, Eve directly (as is often the case with women and seduction and witchcraft) and Adam both indirectly (by failing to lead and take righteous authority to protect his wife, by standing by and not speaking up and telling her to not follow her desires because he too desired the fruit). Men often hearken to women still, by seeking out seduction and personal gratification, avoiding responsibility, being cowardly or beta males.

12. God sent them from the garden to protect them from that punishment becoming eternal. Then he came in the flesh to atone for that sin of hearkening to their new master (Satan). It is tgerefor only possible to return to a state where God is our master by accepting that atonement through accepting the forgiveness brought ablut in tge death, burial and ressurection of Yeshua ha'Messiach, whom most call Jesus, the Christ, messish to the Jews.

Comment: Please [edit] this to fix your typos.

Comment: This looks like your own personal interpretation. Please [edit] this to add references or quotes to other Christian authors because personal interpretation is off-topic here.